# Display manufacturers name in product list (Prestashop 1.7)

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to display manufacturer in category view using Prestashop 1.7.

Prestashop 1.7 uses a new file system with partials, the file I'm trying to edit is located in /themes/**your_theme**/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl

I've been researching and trying a few things like {$product.manufacturer_name} which seems to be correct, It's declared in Product Class, but somehow it doesn't works.

Any clue about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution, this .tpl view has access to id_manufacturer but not manufacturer_name, thats weird, but I finally managed to get the manufacturer name using this code:

```
{Manufacturer::getNameById((int) $product.id_manufacturer)}
```

You have to be inside this file:
/themes/your_theme/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl

Hope it helps